# Mysql Database Can't Find

Tags: mysql, database

I am attempting to migrate a mysql database called "employment" but it's not showing in either phpmyadmin or if I search for the database in the terming using a mysql command.

The database is working so I know it exists.

The configuration variables in the config file point to localhost so it's in the local server.

If I look in /var/lib/mysql folder, I see the employment database along with two other databases that I can see in phpmyadmin.

If I log into mysql using the terminal and query a list of databases, it returns database1 and database2 but not the employment database.

Likewise, if I log into phpmyadmin, it returns database1 and database2 but not the employment database.

If I make changes to the database variables in the site's config file, the page breaks so I know the database is configured correctly to localhost.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try doing this: "cat /var/log/mysql/mysql.log" see if there is any logs being generated. Also, would it be fair to assume that you are logging in as root into mysql?

Comment: No logs in that directory. However, there are log files in /var/lib/mysql/ - And no I am logging in as the username and password I log into myphpadmin with. I will see if it will let me log in as root

Comment: Migrate how? `mysqldump`?

Comment: Go to /etc/mysql/my.cnf and check where the log files are being dumped.

Comment: Mysql does not let me log in as root

Comment: Marcus Adams - preferably through phpmyadmin but I don't mind using mysqldump either.

Comment: my.cnf file:  # Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = 12345
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = 12345
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr

Comment: Probably you aren't granted the permission to view and edit the table. [**GRANT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html).

Comment: Your comment cuts up after certain number of characters, only check for the lines that mentions the logs. I would also concur with mind-404, but I'm not sure how you would elevate privileges without having privileges to view it.

Comment: mind-404 - Even if I didn't have rights to edit the table, I think I should still at least be able to view the list of all available databases.

Comment: codehitman - that is the entire my.cnf file contents - nothing was cut off in the comment

Answer (score 0):

Probably you aren't granted the permission to access the database.

[**GRANT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

Ask your administrator or someone else who is authorized to change your user rights.